# Was there any planned, ultimate resolution to the storyline of the Dead Zone television series?

Tags: deadzone

I'm referring to the Anthony Michael Hall, Nicole DeBoer series of 2002. Senator Stillson was a very different character from either the book or the movie, and had a lot more development.

Does anyone have any information on what the final resolution of the apocalyptic storyline was to be?

Comment: It probably didn't help that the creator [died](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Michael_Piller) two years before the show was cancelled.

Comment: Yup. I felt like the show stayed pretty strong throughout, though. I was bummed that year when they cancelled both that and the 4400. He made a great contribution to DS9 as well, from what I understand.

Answer (score 3):

According to sci-fi blogger [John Keegan](http://forums.usanetwork.com/index.php?showtopic=393536), the "cliffhangers" at the series end were actually pretty well resolved;

> As it stands, this could be the series finale. The writers left the
>   door open, especially in terms of Armageddon, but nearly every
>   character arc has come to a point of resolution. Walt’s legacy is
>   complete, Purdy has turned the corner on his search for redemption,
>   Bruce has found a life for himself, and Johnny is with Sarah and JJ.
>
> There is one hint for the future, if the series is renewed for a
>   seventh season. **Had Sarah remained with Stillson, her presence would
>   have prevented Armageddon (or so Herb’s visionary statement seemed to
>   imply).**

In 2008 actor Anthony Michael Hall stated that he was hoping that there would be a sequel film but that the show itself "***ran its course***" suggesting that any further plot developments would have been written *after* confirmation was received that the show had been reprieved.

If you want an idea of how the show was likely to progress, you can view a [show bible](http://www.zen134237.zen.co.uk/Dead_Zone/Season_4/The_Dead_Zone_Season_4_Writers%27_Guide.pdf) for series 4 here. It's pretty much "Monster of the week" territory from season 3 onwards...